# Jquery is not working on IE10

Tags: jquery

The below script works properly on the firefox and hides the Page Rating & Last modified divs however it is not working on IE-10, am I missing anything?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../PublishingImages/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() { 
     $(".right-wp-zone-col").hide();
     $(".ms-descriptiontext").filter(".ewiki-margin").hide();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: could u check for the browser mode and  Document mode of IE. Set it to Standard for both and then check.

Comment: yes, it works...however I may not expect all the users to do it...is there a fix?

Comment: Are you seeing an JS errors in the IE Developer Toolbar?

Comment: For full backward compability you should use the 1.x versions of jQuery (this goes for the very majority on SharePoint installations)

Comment: No, I dont see any JS errors..whereas could see anything related to html.."<body>" tag found. Only one "<body>" tag should exist per document.

Comment: yes...we have fix for it. we can control the document mode and browser mode using Doctype tag. Let me answer for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery 2.x explicitly doesn't support IE 6-8; the document mode that SharePoint 2010 sets may be causing problems (i.e. causing IE 10 to act more like IE8). As Robert suggests, try the latest 1.x jQuery instead.