# Page Viewer WebPart Not Consistent

Tags: internet-explorer, page-viewer-web-part, firefox

I have been working on a particular aspx page that I put at `/_layouts/mydir/mypage.aspx`

I have a virtual-folder in IIS under Sharepoint that points to the aforesaid address, which allows me to load custom pages directly at `https://my.portal.com/mydir/*`.

Now, I have a page-viewer webpart in a wiki page at `https://my.portal.com/sitepages/aWikiPage.aspx`  which loads the aforementioned address.

This page displays perfectly:

- In both Chrome and Firefox at `https://my.portal.com/mydir/mypage.aspx`
- In Internet Explorer (11) at `https://my.portal.com/mydir/mypage.aspx`
- In both Chrome and Firefox at `https://my.portal.com/sitepages/aWikiPage.aspx` (via the webpart)

But I *can't* get Internet Explorer to load `https://my.portal.com/sitepages/aWikiPage.aspx` (via the webpart) like the other browsers.  And what I don't get is that I can load it directly without any problem.  It loads the basic stuff but none of the primary content ([using gg_OrgChart](https://github.com/gllona/lib-gg-orgchart)) with jQuery 1.11 ([for IE compatibility](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/82828/jquery-is-not-working-on-ie10)).

Something in the Page-Viewer webpart is messing things up for *just* Internet Explorer.  I've tried the compatibility settings in IE, and I can see the same issue on a different computer.  I hate Internet Explorer.

Does anyone have a clue for me?

**[update]**

I [found this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109826/ie9-document-mode-toggle-fixes-sharepoint-css-issues), and so I tried adding this line to my custom master page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

But that doesn't seem to help with a regular installation of Internet Explorer 11.  In IE's Developer's Toolbar, I can see that the default browser level is `9 (default)` but it fails to render in that mode when the page is loaded.

[image: IE Developer's Toolbar Document Mode]

It also fails in `8`.  But if I change it to `7` or `8` and then to `9 (default)` the page loads correctly (the screenshot will look the same both before and after the changes!).  But changing the document mode in the IE developer's toolbar is artificial.  I have tried putting the meta tag at the top of the `<head>` area and just below the `<title>` tag - both to no avail.  [This page says something](http://www.siolon.com/blog/ie-8-compatibility-mode-and-sharepoint/) about IE defaulting to compatibility mode on intranet sites, but I know that IE is not in compatibility mode.  When I close the Web Devloper panel, it goes back to normal (not working).

I've [also tried this hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600100/en-us) where the [server fails to realize](http://gigajim.com/blog/2012/12/11/sharepoint-2010-and-ie10-incompatibility) the browser user agent.  And I've [tried this little trick](http://www.markadrake.com/examples/sharepoint/ie11-fix/), too.

I know IE is able to render this properly!  How can I fix this for good for any instance of a non-tampered IE11 (Did I say I hate Internet Explorer)?

*[update]*

Does anyone have a comment or even a +1 for support here?  It's been a week already.  At least offer your sympathies!

*[update]*

If have discovered that if I take the same page and show it *without* the Sharepoint wrapper (that is, in a separate page even within the Sharepoint virtual directory and use a direct url: `https://my.portal.com/mydir/mypage.aspx`) that it works no matter what the IE browser mode is set to in the page.

But as soon as you wrap it in Sharepoint, it fails to display unless you set the browser to IE browser mode 11 using IE's developer tools.  I hate Internet Explorer!

*[bump]*

Does anyone have any advice at all?

Comment: The virtual directory seems to me to be an unnecessary complexity. Can't you just put the page in Site Pages?

Comment: No; because I'm using uncompiled code in the pages.  However, as I said, I've got no problems except in IE.